# Match partial string with regex

Tags: regex

I've a little problem with a simple regex.

I'd like a regex to match this simple string (in a xml file)  where wsse: could be optional and in particular something like this: < wsse:Username > (wsse is optional).

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance for your kind help!

Comment: The question is, why are you trying to parse XML content as a string?

Comment: Also, please supply a sample of the XML and what you are expecting to get out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match the username:

```
<(?:wsse:)?([^>]+)>
```

**Edit:**
And to allow for any string before the colon:

```
<(?:[^:]+:)?([^>]+)>
```

Comment: Thanks Jerry for your response, but the prefix wsse: could be variable (lenght and string as well). Can you help me?

Comment: This regular expression will actually match whether the ":wsse" is there or not.

Comment: @mauro-dev If you mean anything before the colon, try this: <(?:[^:]+:)?([^>]+)>

Answer (score 0):

Although not the ideal solution (as you really should be parsing XML using an XML parser or XSLT), the following will work for you:

```
<((wsse:)?Username)>(.*)(</\1>)
```

It will also return 4 groups per match.

Group 3 will return the actual username from within the tags